# Setup Directory Permissions For Multiple Users To Read/Write

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, chown

I am trying to figure out how to setup the permissions on a directory `(/apps)` so both the `root` user, and another user `justin` can read, and write into the directory.

The user justin is part of the group `devs`.

/apps has permissions of `drwxrwsr-x`, with owner root and group devs. Additionally it has gid set; `chmod g+s /apps`

The problem is, with the root user if I touch a file (test) inside /apps the owner is root and group is devs. The permissions on the file is `-rw-r--r--`. If I switch to the user justin and try and modify test I get permission denied.

Basically, what is the best way to achieve this? I want it where root can create directories and files, and `justin` can read and write those files and directories. This needs to be automated, as files and directories are created it just works, doing a manual update of permissions is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You have better part of the solution figured out, the only thing left to do is correct permissions for things created by root. There are at least two approaches

1. You can modify the root-side process to call `chmod` after modifying a file. I do not think it is applicable to your case, because then you'd probably just call `chown` and `chmod` and didn't set up sgid directory.
2. You can modify `umask` for the root process. I think it would be better to modify umask just for this process, not for root environment, because sometimes root touches files other users shouldn't mess with, and it's usually better to remember to open access than to close gaps. Therefore, you could add `umask 0007` in front of call to the binary that runs as root.

Comment: Is there a way when root, and creating a file or directory, to force the owner to be `justin` instead of root. I think that would solve the problem as well.

Comment: To change file owner you can run chown, but it would have to be run after each file creation. If you can automate that, then great. You can set umask for a process, and then you don't need changing file ownership after its creation by root. Choose whichever you like :).

Comment: If I simply set umask 0002 how long does that last? Until I logout? Until I restart the server?

Comment: It works in the shell, in which it was invoked, until the shell terminates. If you want to change it for all root logins, then edit /etc/bashrc, but I would recommend against it. umask 0022 for root is there for a cause.